# Genric/Anonymous type injecting using Guice

Tags: java, binding, guice

I am trying to bind a concrete class with generic parameter. 
eg:

```
public class Concrete<T> extends GenericClass<T, Employee>{

 public Employee method(T input){
 //Do stuff
 }
}
```

now my other class uses multiple object of this concrete class
eg:

```
public class UseConcrete{

private Concrete<Class1> concrete1;
private Concrete<Class2> concrete2;     

@Inject
publicUseConcrete(Concrete<Class1> concrete1,Concrete<Class2> concrete2){
this.concrete1 = concrete1;
this.concrete2 = concrete2;
}

}
```

I am wondering if the simple bind like this would work? I am going to try this but just want to see if I am on the wrong track.

```
bind(Concrete.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as other requirements are satisfied (no-arg constructor, or with `@Inject`), then `bind(Concrete.class)` will work.

You can then do the following:

```
Concrete<String> concrete = injector.getInstance(Concrete.class);
```

or in your example:

```
injector.getInstance(UseConcrete.class);
```

According to official documentation you can also do:

A)

```
@Override public void configure() {
    bind(new TypeLiteral<Concrete<T>>() {}).toInstance(new Concrete<T>());
}
```

B)

```
@Provides Concrete<T> providesConcrete() {
   return new Concrete<T>();
}
```

where `T` needs to be replaced with the actual type you are trying to bind. You can read official documentation [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-to-inject-class-with-generic-type).

Comment: My UseConcrete is the class where I want to inject Concrete class. Which is what I have done in the constructor of UseConcrete. Would that work?